# How to fix "Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property open on object SpreadsheetApp"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have only pasted a part of the code which I am trying to run separately.

```
function myFunction() {
   var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Companies_OHLC_0"');
   while (files.hasNext()) {
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());
    }
 }
```

it was working sometime back but I keep getting this exception now:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property open on object SpreadsheetApp. (line 4, file "Code").

Comment: I have tried OpenByID() and OpenByurl(), still no luck

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
I had multiple files with the same name and hence, i was getting that exception.

I had run other scripts which had created new files with the same names.I had not noticied this. I deleted all the duplciate files and I am not getting this exception any more.