# Is it possible to convert a .txt file to a google doc in an apps script? I keep throwing errors and I'm wondering what I'm missing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I commented out my attempt as it keeps failing... any thoughts?

```js
// script to be run on below noted folder and output to second specified folder in same drive
// converts spreadsheets to TXT files

function convertSpreadsheetsToDocs() {
  const mainFolderName = "Test Spreadsheets"; // Replace with your main folder name
  const subFolderName = "Subfolder5"; // Replace with your subfolder name

  const mainFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(mainFolderName).next();
  const subFolder = mainFolder.createFolder(subFolderName); // Create a subfolder

  const spreadsheets = mainFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
    const spreadsheet = spreadsheets.next();
    const spreadsheetName = spreadsheet.getName();
    const docName = spreadsheetName + " (Converted)";
    const doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
    
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.getId()).getActiveSheet();
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = dataRange.getValues();
    dataRange.setNumberFormat("@"); // Set cell format as plain text
    
    let text = values.map(row => row.join("\t")).join("\n"); // Convert data to tab-delimited     text
    // Replace carriage return with page break
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\n\n");
    // Replace tab with carriage return
    text = text.replace(/\t/g, "\n");

    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
    //   const blob = Utilities.newBlob(text, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
    const docFile = subFolder.createFile(blob.setName(docName + ".txt"));

    // File.setContentType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
    DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).setTrashed(true); // Delete the temporary Google Doc
  }
  
  Logger.log("Spreadsheets converted to text file successfully.");
}
```

I can create the .txt file from a spreadsheet but fail when trying to make it a google doc. In the end I need to add some formatting... remove the first five or so lines and tag a font to it to make it pretty

Comment: About your question of `Is it possible to convert a .txt file to a google doc in an apps script?`, I think that it's yes. But, about `I can create the .txt file from a spreadsheet but fail when trying to make it a google doc.`, when I saw your showing script, I cannot understand the relationship between that and your script. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And also, can I ask you about your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thanks your your interest Tanaike, We had a dump from a database to spreadsheets which I was asked to convert to google docs. Some of the beginning of my script strips out formatting and makes it pretty text. Next I tried to save it as a google doc but     // File.setContentType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
did not work, I only had success saving them as .txt. I tried creating another script yesterday to just open .txt and make it a google doc but had no luck there either.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have one more question. About `Some of the beginning of my script strips out formatting and makes it pretty text`, in this case, are you required to keep the text style (for example, the font color, bold, italic, and so on)? If my understanding is correct, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I think I figured it out... below, different approach this time. No, I wasn't trying to save formatting from the spreadsheet but was asked after I had coded the above to add formatting, which as a .txt file wasn't possible and I couldn't figure out how to convert it to a doc file in the script. If I could have just done the above and converted to a doc I would have been nearly done. I'm in over my head so otherwise pretty happy to get something running. Need to learn more!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300360/13771937) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123383/creating-a-document-full-of-images-with-google-apps-script), it does not seem `createFile` is able to create files of the `Google Docs` mime type.

As an alternative, you can create a new (blank) doc file (via the `DocumentApp` or advanced `Drive` API), and then append elements from the spreadsheet to that document. Depending on how you want things formatted in the final product, this could be quite tedious, but in the simplest case you could do something like so:

```
// script to be run on below noted folder and output to second specified folder in same drive
// converts spreadsheets to TXT files

function convertSpreadsheetsToDocs() {
  const mainFolderName = "Test Spreadsheets"; // Replace with your main folder name
  const subFolderName = "Subfolder5"; // Replace with your subfolder name

  const mainFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(mainFolderName).next();
  const subFolder = mainFolder.createFolder(subFolderName); // Create a subfolder

  const spreadsheets = mainFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  while (spreadsheets.hasNext()) {
    const spreadsheet = spreadsheets.next();
    const spreadsheetName = spreadsheet.getName();
    const docName = spreadsheetName + " (Converted)";
    // const doc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
    
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheet.getId()).getActiveSheet();
    const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    const values = dataRange.getValues();
    dataRange.setNumberFormat("@"); // Set cell format as plain text
    
    let text = values.map(row => row.join("\t")).join("\n"); // Convert data to tab-delimited     text
    // Replace carriage return with page break
    text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\n\n");
    // Replace tab with carriage return
    text = text.replace(/\t/g, "\n");

    const driveFile = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, title: docName, parents: [{id: subFolder.getId()}]});
    const docId = driveFile.id;
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
    // Either run the above three lines with the advanced Drive API enabled or the next two lines
    // const doc = DocumentApp.create(docName); 
    // DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).moveTo(subFolder);

    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.appendParagraph(text)
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
  
  Logger.log("Spreadsheets converted to text file successfully.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I went out for a walk and came up with similar... not enough room here so I'll post it as answering my question but before I do, though the script works, it throws an error. I'm going to run it anyway as it produces the files I need. Curious if you have any idea how to kill the error I get from Line 11: 9:43:28 PM Error 
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property open on object SpreadsheetApp.
copyDataToGoogleDoc @ Code.gs:11

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked and note above in comment back to Miguel, has an error but it runs so I'm running with it.

```js
function copyDataToGoogleDoc() {
  var sourceFolderName = "Test Spreadsheets"; // Replace with the name of your source folder
  var targetFolderName = "Test Target 5"; // Replace with the name of your target subfolder

  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolderName).next();
  var targetFolder = sourceFolder.createFolder(targetFolderName);
  var files = sourceFolder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // Create a new Google Doc for each sheet file
    var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(file.getName());

    // Loop through each row and copy data from specified columns
    for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
      var rowData = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0];
      var combinedData = rowData[0] + " - " + rowData[1] + " - " + rowData[3] + " - " + rowData[4];

// Append the combined data in bold font as a new paragraph in the Google Doc
      newDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(combinedData).setBold(true);

      // Append the long text string from column 5 on a new line (skip a line)
      newDoc.getBody().appendParagraph("");
      newDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(rowData[5]).setBold(false);

      // Append a new paragraph before pasting the next row's data
      newDoc.getBody().appendParagraph("");
    }

    // Move the new Google Doc to the target subfolder
    var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
    targetFolder.addFile(newFile);
    sourceFolder.removeFile(newFile);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry are you saying there's an error in your code or mine? I ran both and I did not get any error, so not sure I can help you. If you are referring to an error in your line 11 `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);` Just browsing similar errors, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62964515/13771937) works for you.